# Android error caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: myapp.MyFunction

Tags: java, android

I am having an application in production which is, usually, working fine. However, I have received a very strange error report. The application failed due to a NoClassDefFoundError.

After doing some intense investigation I have understood that this error is usually happening when the library is not properly set, or the file is not properly declared and later on not found for the class dependant.

However, this is strange, as my apk is already compiled and perfectly operational in several devices, so the library is compiled.

What I actually crushing is an asynctask like this:

```
  String result_add = new MyFunction().execute(param1, param2).get();
```

When the code reaches this point, crushes with the exception of NoClassDefFoundError referring to MyFunction class, re testing in my devices, is working smoothly.

So, it is not the error of SDK17 [described here](http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17) and is not a wrong import. Device is version 2.3.6

Any idea how can I further investigate or which could be the error source?

Comment: Try testing your app on the exact same device that exhibited the problem.  If you do not have access to that physical device, then create and AVD with the same API level.

Comment: offtopic: What a waste of time ... Why are you using AsyncTask at all if you are using `get()`? There is a easiest way to do a seppuku - just dissable StrictMode ... Using AsyncTask only to avoid NetworkOnMainThreadException and then making AsyncTask synchronous again with get() make no sens at all... this exception is to force you to not block the UI thread ... with get you block it again

Comment: @EJK the device is actually the same OS version that one of the testing device I have, but not the same device. Will the emulator make the difference?

Comment: No I just suggested the emulator because it is a convenient way to test a hardware/OS combination when you do not have access to a physical device.

Comment: Arg, thanks for it anyhow!